# How to show different content in a same page using URL query string?

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the message from a database in admin dashboard with a url '**admin/view-messages.php**'.

After clicking **Read message** the url should change to **admin/view-messages.php?message=show** but the page should be same.

My Code:-

```
<div class="panel-body">
                  <?php
                    if($_GET['message'] == 'show'){
                      echo $_GET['message'];
                    }
                  ?>
                  <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Name</th>
                              <th>Email</th>
                              <th>Website</th>
                              <th>Phone</th>
                              <th>Message</th>
                              <th>Status</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <?php
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                          ?>
                          <tr class="odd gradeX">
                              <td><?php echo $row[name]; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row[email]; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row[website]; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row[phone]; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row[message]; ?></td>
                              <td>
                                <?php
                                  $status = $row["status"];
                                  if($status == 1){
                                      echo "<a href=view-messages.php?message=show>Read</a>";
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    echo "<a href=view-messages.php?message=show>Unread</a>";
                                  }
                                ?>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php
                                }
                              }else {
                                echo "0 results found";
                              }
                          ?>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

Here, I display the message just to check. It is simple and working. But after I click the read message it will show the single message **details**.

```
if($_GET['message'] == 'show'){
                      echo $_GET['message'];
                    }
```

How this be possible?

Comment: change `<a href=view-messages.php?message=show>Read</a>` to `<a href='view-messages.php?message=show'>Read</a>`

Comment: @MRustamzade The code is running properly. But when I add the code from <table> tag in the else { echo ...} part. The script is not running.